# Cant create branch on Bitbucket that starts with feature/

Tags: bitbucket

Im using the same repo for years and years now, and last week i ran in to an issues when i was trying to push my code

This is the error im getting

```
remote: Permission denied to create branch feature/jiraissue.
To bitbucket.org:repo.git
 ! [remote rejected]     feature/jiraissue -> feature/jiraissue (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'bitbucket.org:repo.git'
```

And the same goes for all branches i create when im naming them feature/

If i do something like this, it works fine.

```
git push --set-upstream origin feat/hello
```

Comment: I don't see a question here? The error clearly states that you don't have permissions to create that branch.

Comment: Bitbucket provide, as a feature, the ability to restrict particular users away from particular branch names / patterns. Whoever controls this Bitbucket repository specifically told it to not let *you* (or maybe *everyone but Frank* or something) to have the name `feature/jiraissue`. Check the "branch restrictions" rules over on Bitbucket for this repository.

Comment: Yes. But what im wondering is what could have happend from one day to another? I have hade no issues for a few years with this branch names.

Comment: @torek Thanks! It looks like some one has been in here and messing around with our settings